# Custom code injection into Squarespace Five Template

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I am trying to utilize custom CSS to replace the normally static header banner with an image slider. There are a few custom options listed in forums, but all don't apply to the mobile version of the site. Here is the closest code I've found:

```
 #collection-BLAH {
   /* Remove left right and top padding from content area */
   #page-body-wrapper {
     padding: 0 0 24px
   }
   /* Allow gallery to span full width of browser window */
   #page-body {
     max-width: none
   }
   /* Add spacing back to sides of lower section of content area */
   #page-BLAH {
     max-width: 1140px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 24px 20px 0 20px;
   }
   /* Hide built-in banner area */
   #banner-area-wrapper {
     display: none;
   }
   /* Set gallery height */
   .sqs-gallery {
     max-height: 350px;
   }
 }
```

However, this doesn't apply to mobile. I also got a bit confused by what the poster meant by #collection-BLAH and #page-BLAH. In the comments they said: Replace #collection-BLAH with your own page ID.
Replace #page-BLAH with your own ID from the 2nd child of the #content.

That still confused me. Basically I'm just trying to replace header image with a full-width scrolling image banner. Thanks in advance if anyone is able to assist!

Comment: please provide it in fiddle.